# I want to show stars based on an array element that is passed as a parameter to my template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

So I was trying to loop over an array element which id {{doctor.16}} but I couldn't so I thought I could make it as if conditions but I failed to do this too so can anyone please help me?

this is what I have done so far

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="single_jobs white-bg d-flex justify-content-between" style="width: 50px">
                        <div class="single_candidates text-center">
                            {% for doctor in recdoc %}
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img class="img-circle " src="{% static 'static_file/img/candiateds/2.png' %}" alt="" >
                            </div>
                            <a href="" ><h4 >{{doctor.6}}  {{doctor.7}}</h4></a>
                            <p> {{doctor.9}}</p>
                            <div class="best-rating">
                                <div class="text-warning">
                                    {% if{{doctor.16}} == 1 %}
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    {% endif %}

                                </div>
                                <div class="best-rating" >
                                    <h5>تقييم الدكتور</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                              {% endfor %}

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

what I can't do correctly is this part

```html
{% if{{doctor.16}} == 1 %}
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not rendering the variable within **{% if %}** tag.

The part you did wrong should be:

```
{% if doctor.16 == 1 %}
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
{% endif %}
```

See the following official documentation for more details of django templates:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#syntax